# MVC3 - Deserialize javascript object to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having trouble to pass the serialized js object to controller and let the default model binder automtatically deserialize it into my object.

I can manually deserialize the value into my object, it's all fine. but I would like to know why it doesn't work.

Thanks

Here is my code snippet

js code

```
$.post('/Order/AddRecordAddHocStock2', { idPatient: $patientId, "orderItems": JSON.stringify($orderItems) }, function (data) {
                //$("#recordingdialog").html(data).dialog("open");

                var $dialog = $("#popup_dialog2");

                $dialog.empty();
                $dialog
                .dialog({
                    bgiframe: true,
                    title: $title,
                    height: 700,
                    width: 650,
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false
                });

                $dialog.html(data).dialog("open");

            });
```

Here is the post value get it from firefox

```
idPatient   72
orderItems     [{"Id":0,"ProductName":"01870","Quantity":0,"StockOnHand":0,"MaxAllowance":12,"OrderTotal":0},{"Id":0,"ProductName":"01870","Quantity":0,"StockOnHand":0,"MaxAllowance":1,"OrderTotal":0}]
```

Here is my controller which I expected the orderItems should be automatically populate the value from the previous js object

```
        [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult AddRecordAddHocStock2(long idPatient, List<OrderItemModel> orderItems)
    {
       var items = Request.Form["orderItems"];
       //it's working if I manually deserialize the js object
       var data = new   JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(items,typeof(List<OrderItemModel>));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the content-type to "application/json". See this blog post for more details. Focus on the jQuery code sample, not the server side changes which are unnecessary in ASP.NET MVC 3: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx

Comment: jquery $.post does not support content-type. I tried with $.ajax, it works, but I now have another problem, when I get the data back, the jquery raise parseerror. the status is 200, but statstext shows error

Comment: You'll probably need to post more information about the new error. Perhaps a new question with more details. Is there a server exception being thrown? What does Fiddler show as the response? Etc.

Comment: Hi Haacked
I solved the problem. I had another issue with the date querystring, the default model binder can't bind it to my controller's parameter. my date format looks like dd/MM/yyyy